# yarn build failing in Symfony 7; Module not found but can see it in vendor folder

Tags: php, reactjs, symfony, webpack

I am running Symfony 7.0 and attempting to use the `symfony/ux-react` bundle.

I set this up using the following command `composer require symfony/ux-bundle` followed by `npm install -D @babel/preset-react --force`.

The bundle has been installed correctly as I can see by checking the `vendor` directory, but when attempting to run `yarn watch` I get the following error:

> Module build failed: Module not found:
> "./assets/app.js" contains a reference to the file "@symfony/ux-react".
> This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.

This is my **assets/app.js** file:

```js
import { registerReactControllerComponents } from '@symfony/ux-react';
import './bootstrap.js';
/*
 * Welcome to your app's main JavaScript file!
 *
 * This file will be included onto the page via the importmap() Twig function,
 * which should already be in your base.html.twig.
 */
import './styles/app.css';

registerReactControllerComponents(require.context('./react/controllers', true, /\.(j|t)sx?$/));
registerReactControllerComponents();
```

This is my **package.json** file:

```json
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.17.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.0",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.23.3",
        "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^4.0.0",
        "core-js": "^3.23.0",
        "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9",
        "webpack": "^5.74.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
        "webpack-notifier": "^1.15.0"
    },
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
        "dev": "encore dev",
        "watch": "encore dev --watch",
        "build": "encore production --progress"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@symfony/stimulus-bridge": "^3.2.2",
        "react": "^18.2.0"
    }
}
```

The `symfony/ux-react` module is exactly where it should be, so far as I can see; at `/vendor/symfony/`.

I have run through all steps in the setup as per the documentation  with no luck.

Comment: Did you `npm install` after requiring the the bundle via composer, as it is stated in the documentation when using Encore?

Comment: does the path you're using to import @symfony/ux-react matches its actual location in your node_modules folder?

Comment: Try to reinstall Node Modules,  remember to do a backup,  Delete your node_modules folder and yarn.lock file and so run "yarn install" again to reinstall all packages.